# Spring Data JPA with a custom RepositoryFactory and Multiple EntityManagers

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently trying to get Spring Data JPA to work with two DataSources and thus two EntityManagers. My Repositories all inherit from a custom base class "BaseRepositoryImpl".

**Problem:**
I always get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: 
expected single bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory1,entityManagerFactory2
```

**Question:**
How can I tell my custom RepositoryFactory which EntityManagerFactory to use?

Here's my Spring configuration:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="package1" transaction-manager-ref="..."
  factory-class="MyFactoryBean"
  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory1"/>  

<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="..." />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unit1" />   
  ...
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="package2" transaction-manager-ref="..."
  factory-class="MyFactoryBean"
  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory2"/>  

<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="..." />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unit2" />   
  ...
</bean>
```

The class "MyFactoryBean" is implemented exactly as described at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories.

The configuration "entity-manager-factory-ref" seems to be ignored by Spring, at least when using a custom RepositoryFactory.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you post a stack trace and perhaps the code where the error is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity manager factory is used to create entity managers for different persistence units. You declare your entity manager bean and then give entity manager factory bean as it's class.

This is what worked for me:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="defaultEntityManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.default.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.default.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.default.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultEntityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="defaultDataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="defaultPersistenceUnit"/>
</bean>

<bean id="otherDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.other.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.other.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.other.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="otherEntityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="otherDataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="otherPersistenceUnit"></property>
</bean>
```

Then when you are implementing your data access classes just declare:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class MyDAOImpl implements MyDAO
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "defaultPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

and for DAO that uses other persistence unit:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class MyOtherDAOImpl implements MyOtherDAO
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "otherPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```